# Why the "Initialize Repository" on VScode not available

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, initialization, repository

I have an assignment that require me to create a markdown and push it to GitHub. My issue is the "Initialize Repository" is not showing. The .md file is saved in the folder linked to Github but it is still can't initialize it. Help! Here is a screenshot [Missing Initialize Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLdaH.png)

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to save the files, commit, then push. You didn't save the files, thus it won't let you commit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, when trying to push an existing folder, the `Initialize Repository` option will always be missing. One way to approach this is to open your terminal in VS Code while already within the folder of interest, and try the following:

```
git init
git remote add origin YOUR_ORIGIN_URL.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

This has worked for every project I needed to connect to a GitLab origin.